# How does Islam balance worship with other activities?

Tags: practical-islam

Is there a balance in how Muslims are encouraged to live their lives between worship and other pursuits? I am looking for answers that cover the following points:

- The relationship between worship, work, money, and family
- The Prophet (saws)'s balance
- Earning money to support one's family

Comment: The title seems not to be correctly depicting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**English translation of the Quran by [Muhsin Khan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Muhsin_Khan)**

> http://quran.com/62/9
>  O you who believe (Muslims)! When the call
>   is proclaimed for the Salat (prayer) on the day of Friday (Jumu'ah
>   prayer), come to the remembrance of Allah [Jumu'ah religious talk
>   (Khutbah) and Salat (prayer)] and leave off business (and every other
>   thing), that is better for you if you did but know!

---

> http://quran.com/62/10 
> Then when the (Jumu'ah) Salat (prayer) is
>   finished, you may disperse through the land, and seek the Bounty of
>   Allah (by working, etc.), and remember Allah much, that you may be
>   successful.

---

**My personal view of the 2 sections above (so take with a pinch of salt)**

These 2 sections of the Quran to me seem to be saying that when it's time for worship, worship! When it's time to work, work! Work could possibly be considered a type of worship if your have the correct intention.  However, I'm no scholar, so you should probably get this clarified by someone more reputable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a scholar, but Islam places enough importance on your work, your studies.
If you're working, work diligently, and when you hear the call for prayer, pause the work, and go pray.

Sometimes your work may need sometime to be put in a state where it can be paused so that it can be resumed correctly. For that, many of the Salats have considerable amount of gap between the call and the salat. For the salats which don't have enough gap (e.g. Maghrib), you may preempt the halt and start preparing for it before the Call for prayer.

This is similar to what the above comment said.

Having a family and supporting it is one of the Sunnah (as far as I know).
I never came across something which supports complete abandonment of your family so that you can be involved in worship only.
You are required to worship in the same way as you're required to provide various levels of assistance to your family/parents/wife/kids.
I mean that's why there only 5 Salats in a day...

Being on the path of deen is also a kind of worship.
Being a good Muslim involves being a good human as well. Tender, Kind, Helpful, Just, And Truthful. Allah likes it, and when you do stuff to please Allah, in his name, it’s also a kind of worship.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  Here we require answers to contain references/citations.  Please edit your answer and add citations/references so to raise it's quality, thank you.